# postfix loop back email issue - plesk

Tags: email, loops, exchange-server, external

I am fairly new to plesk and postfix so please bear with me. I have plesk setup on a server with multiple domains already living and breathing, including email which all works fine. My issue comes in with a new domain I added that is using exchange for the email instead of the local postfix. So I deactivated postfix for this "newdomin.tld" in plesk but anytime the website tries to send an email (PHP Contact form) I never get the test emails (despite the form reporting success).

Here are the errors I get in my **maillog**:

```
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/qmgr[22665]: 15F972500E30: from=<phpform@newdomin.tld>, size=836, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/smtp[22852]: 15F972500E30: to=<validuser@newdomin.tld>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX loops back to myself)
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/cleanup[22750]: 2EB332500EEF: message-id=<20150730150019.2EB332500EEF@mydomain.com>
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/bounce[22853]: 15F972500E30: sender non-delivery notification: 2EB332500EEF
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/qmgr[22665]: 2EB332500EEF: from=<>, size=2630, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/qmgr[22665]: 15F972500E30: removed
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/smtp[22852]: 2EB332500EEF: to=<validuser@newdomin.tld>, relay=none, delay=0.03, delays=0.03/0/0/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX loops back to myself)
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain postfix/qmgr[22665]: 2EB332500EEF: removed
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain plesk_saslauthd[22790]: activity on 0 channel(s)
Jul 30 08:00:19 mydomain plesk_saslauthd[22790]: select timeout, exiting
```

And here is my **main.cf**

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
#mydestination = localhost.$mydomain, localhost, localhost.localdomain
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
    mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.8.17/README_FILES
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual, hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix_default.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = $smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
mynetworks =
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access     hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,
        reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
        reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
        reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
        reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net,
        reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net,
        reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com,
        permit
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailbox_size_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
myhostname = mycustomdomain.com
message_size_limit = 31457280
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is a default plesk setup (12.0.18 Update #57) running on CentOS 6.6. And all other email, webmail, smtp settings seem to work for all other servers, it is just this one that has Exchange. I did make sure all my DNS settings were correct in plesk as well as in my server portal through codero hosting. I know the exchange settings are working as everyone gets their emails i just cant send emails from the domain out tot he exchange server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had gencom.us smtp:206.225.87.101 in my /etc/postfix/transport and /var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport files. once removed things started working again.